# Creating Labels at run time from a variable

Tags: c#

Im trying to create a label in runtime. the number of labels depends on the number of items of another variable and the labels do not show. The code is as follows.

```
int NoofItems = tillfrm.lvbasket.Items.Count;  
for (int i = 0; i < NoofItems + 1; i++)  
{  
    Label lblitems = new Label();  
    lblitems.Name = "lblItems" + i;  
    lblitems.Font = new Font ("Calibri",lblitems.Font.Size);  
    lblitems.Location = new Point(95, (152 + (19 * i)));  
    lblitems.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;  
    lblitems.Show();  
    lblitems.AutoSize = true;  
    lblitems.Text = tillfrm.lvbasket.Items[0].Text;  
    this.Controls.Add(lblitems);  
}
```

some help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to verify that `NoofItems` is not 0 and that  `tillfrm.lvbasket.Items[0]` is not blank?

Comment: `tillfrm.lvbasket.Items[0].Text`  probably should be `tillfrm.lvbasket.Items[i].Text` and change `i < NoofItems + 1` to `i < NoofItems`

Comment: Have you tried setting the Visibility to true?

Comment: @Valentin That would cause an exception since the user is doing: `i < NoofItems + 1`

Comment: @LarsTech well, he should change it to `i < NoofItems`

Comment: Either the location is off the screen or you are adding the labels to the wrong control.  I've seen cases like this that the new control ends up behind the active control so it can't be seen.

Comment: its not from an array Noofitems is the number of items added to a listveiw control from another form.

Answer (score 3):

You should change `tillfrm.lvbasket.Items[0].Text` to `tillfrm.lvbasket.Items[i].Text`.

And `i < NoofItems + 1` to `i < NoofItems`, because array size is `NoofItems`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, create a function, make the array GLOBAL,

```
protected void myFunction()
{
int NoofItems = tillfrm.lvbasket.Items.Count;  
    for (int i = 0; i < NoofItems; i++)  
    {  
    Label lblitems = new Label();  
    lblitems.Name = "lblItems" + i;  
    lblitems.Font = new Font ("Calibri",lblitems.Font.Size);  
    lblitems.Location = new Point(95, (152 + (19 * i)));  
    lblitems.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;  
    lblitems.Show();  
    lblitems.AutoSize = true;  
    lblitems.Text = tillfrm.lvbasket.Items[i].Text;  
    this.Controls.Add(lblitems);  
    }
}
```

Then call this function in Form_load() function or Page_load() function like this

```
protected void Form_Load(Object sender , EventArgs e)
{
   myFunction();
}
```

Comment: What are you making global?  Where is `this` coming from if you moved your function into a module?  What's the benefit?

Comment: Well, when we create something dynamically, we have to do it within FormLoad event, because we want those dynamically element created everytime not just once. i myself actually am new to c# so no idea about depth.